# Does Emmet work with Sublime Text in Vintage Mode?

Tags: sublimetext2

None of these commands produce a response in Sublime Text 2 on Windows. Emmet is installed. Using vintage mode. Question: how to use Emmet in Vintage Mode on Sublime Text 2?

```
html:5 
div>ul>li
div+p+bq
```

Comment: I have Vintage Mode on, and Emmet works fine for me. Are you saying pressing *Tab* doesnt expand the abbreviation for you? If so, can you try doing `ctrl+e` which should manually force the abbreviation to expand. Check to see if that works.

Comment: @saadq yes, tab doesn't expand the abbreviation. However, `ctrl+e` does. Thank you. If you write an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to manually expand an abbreviation.

You can also try adding the following to your User keybindings in order to make <kbd>Tab</kbd> work normally:

```
{ "keys": ["tab"], "args": {"action": "expand_abbreviation"}, "command": "run_emmet_action", "context": [{"key": "emmet_action_enabled.expand_abbreviation"}]}
```